# Синтаксис jQuery

Tags: jquery

Нужно по клику получить класс a, и скрыть все дивы кроме тех, что имеют идентичный класс.
Подскажите, в чем ошибка, может в синтаксисе?

```
$('a').click(function () {
    var $selected = $(this).attr('class');
    var $ident = $('div').hasClass($selected);
    $('div').hide().filter($ident);
});
```

Comment: может поменять местами вызовы `.hide()` и `.filter()`

Comment: в таком виде как сейчас — hide работает, если поменять местами, то нет. видимо ошибка в переменной. но не могу понять где конкретно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

почему-то сразу не заметил, это же элементарно:

```
$('div').filter(function(){
    return !$(this).hasClass($selected);
}).hide();
```